# Running a server program

Tags: linux, java, service

Okay, I'm experienced client-side developer and now successfully created a server-side app using Java/MongoDB for API and NodeJS for public html responses.

All is okay, except doubts.

**How should I run server executables?**

Currently, I'm running mongodb using `systemd`, so on startup it will launched automatically.

Then, I open `screen` and run NodeJS app using `supervisor` program, it will relaunch the app on crash.

On new tab, I run Java app directly, using `java -jar main/application.jar`

Now, I can detach `screen` and close `ssh`.

**BUT**, Should I wrap these executables to services or it's ok to run like I do?

Answer (score 1):

You should use systemd to start and manage your server applications.

Answer (score 0):

Server stuff **needs to start/stop automatically with the server and run in the background**... on most modern Linux distributions now that's probably going to be done with `systemd` (as lain said). Older distributions would be `system V init` scripts in `/etc/init.d` (or similar) or sometimes `upstart` in `/etc/init` (Ubuntu).

On a personal note, I don't think properly designed daemons (server software/services) should require wrappers/monitors like screen or supervisor for proper operation. They should take care of themselves like most of the other stuff that comes with Linux (seriously, look at it).

Answer (score 0):

If you start the application using screen you can't automatically restart them on reboot.
Below there is a sample code of a systemd script that run an jar application as a service. You can put it in /etc/systemd/system/test.service and then start the service using systemctl start test

This script has been tested on RHEL 7

```
[Unit]
Description=java application descrption
#After=NetworkManager.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /root/tmp/test.jar
ExecStop=pkill -f '/root/tmp/test.jar'
#ExecReload=
PIDFile=/var/run/jboss-as/test.jar.pid

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```